# 2 classes implement same interface and one derives from another

Tags: inheritance, interface, strategy-pattern

I have an interface:

```
Interface I
{
   void Update();
}
```

and 2 classes that implement it, A & B.
Also both of the classes use the same exact function in update but B uses different code later on:

```
Public class A : I
{
   public void Update()
   {
      someFunc();
   }
}

Public class B : I
{
   public void Update().    
   {
      someFunc();
      ....some B code...
   }
}
```

So I thought move someFunc() to A and let B inherit from A since B does what A does plus something else. Is this design ok because it feels not..or can you advise for something better?

I would like to Leave the interface just like in strategy design pattern since later on there can arrive class C that will implement I interface compelitely differently than A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Using inheritance for only code reuse is not a good idea. Only let A inherit if you truly creating a [subtype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). In your case I would create an Abstract Class that contains the common code.

```
Interface I
{
   void Update();
}

abstract class AbstractI : I
{
   someFunc() {
      //implementation
   }
}

Public class A : AbstractI 
{
   public void Update()
   {
      someFunc();
   }
}

Public class B : AbstractI 
{
   public void Update().    
   {
      someFunc();
      ....some B code...
   }
}
```

(never mind the syntax, I made it up - just pseudo code)